# Folium with Mapbox layer blank

Tags: maps, mapbox, geospatial, folium

I am trying to use Folium with a Mapbox layer and it keeps failing with an error: `ValueError: You must pass an API key if using Cloudmade or non-default Mapbox tiles.` I am passing it an API key however.

```py
mapbox_api_key = r"pk.eyJ1Ijoi ... " #the whole key is long, assigned by Mapbox
Map = folium.Map(location=[centroid.geometry.y, centroid.geometry.x],
                 zoom_start=8,
                 tiles = "Mapbox",
                 API_key = mapbox_api_key)
Map.save("map.html")
```

This returns a blank map. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens by using `tiles='"https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=mytoken"'.format(mapbox_api_key)`?

Comment: That yields a blank map as well

Comment: What do you run?

Comment: I was able to successfully produce a map using this code: 
`mapbox_api_key = r"pk.eyJ1Ijo ..."
tileset_ID_str = "streets-v11";
tilesize_pixels = "256";
Map = folium.Map(location=[centroid.geometry.y, centroid.geometry.x], zoom_start=8, tiles = f"https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/{tileset_ID_str}/tiles/{tilesize_pixels}/{{z}}/{{x}}/{{y}}@2x?access_token={mapbox_api_key}", attr="Mapbox")`